# I want to display a logo in PictureBox control irrespective of ImageURL in DevExpress Report control?, how could i do this?

Tags: wpf-controls, devexpress, picturebox, devexpress-windows-ui

There one Print i'm generating in DevExpress Report COntrol and I wanted to show Company logo in the print.
Someone please help me to show image as logo in XRPicturebox control without Database binding and without providing ImageURLi.e. irrespective of path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can set Image via Image Property. Goto `XRPictureBox` properties and on the Image property click on `...` symbol to browse and set the image.

Hope this helps